# A Navigation Stack for Search result for Ionic Framework

Tags: ionic-framework

Does anyone have any idea for the following scenario?

I do have a tab sample and some tab views will integrate with the search bar view/function at the navigation bar.
Views from search results are actually live in some tabs.
How can I share the view of the search results on a certain tab where I have searched for items.
(note that view of a search result is actually live in one of the available tabs)
Here is an example:

I do have three tabs on my platform as follows: 
each of the tabs will have the search bar.

Home | Map | More

I do have a profile view at the "More" tab.

If the user searches for a profile at the "Home" tab, how can I show the existing profile view at the home tab instead? 
Besides that, I would like to make sure the navigation stack for any search results are always staying at the place where the user trigger search function. In this case, any search result navigation stack will
be tracked and displayed at the "Home" tab instead.

You help will be much more appreciated.